# In Bash, file starts with a "-"

Tags: bash

An application created a directory called "-123456" in my /tmp directory.

In Bash, rm -rf * returns:
bash: cd: -7: invalid option

rm -rf "-123456"
Same thing.

Help?

Comment: Don't let this happen!  What is the application?

Comment: @Charles Stewart: Something proprietary from IBM; I can't prevent it.

Comment: You might think of filing a bug report to IBM about this: this is something like bedwetting.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use "--" to end your list of arguments.  Thus: `rm -rf -- -123456`

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried `rm -rf ./-123456`?

Edit: Works for me

```
# ls -l
total 1
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Mar 29 20:48 -test
# rm -rf ./-test
# ls -l
total 0
```

Comment: You're right as well.  Two paths to the same thing.

Comment: However!  What if the file was named "something -12345"? :)

Comment: Easy (Sorry, can't format comments very well):

    $ touch something\ -12345
    $ ls so*
    something -12345
    $ rm something\ -12345 
    $ ls so*
    ls: so*: No such file or directory

Answer (score -1):

Classic basic UNIX puzzle. A more obtuse approach that manages to drag perl into it:

```
perl -e 'unlink "-12345"'
```